# Проверка схемы в JSON

Tags: json, postman, response

как написать схему для проверки полей в респонсе?

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 558,
            "name": "Riyadh",
            "type": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

писал такой код

```
const schema = {
  "data": [
            "id",
            "name",
            "type"],
};

  var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);  

pm.test('Body is correct', function() {
  pm.expect(tv4.validate(data, schema)).to.be.true;
});
```

когда меняю название поля всеравно пишет что тест прошел, при том что поля нет в респонсе

Answer (score 1):

Если поле обязательно в респонсе, то его надо в схеме указать как required.

```
"required": ["id", "name", "type"]
```

Рекомендую https://www.jsonschema.net/